# ggplot: how to move the 0 coordinate to the middle of X-axis?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, coordinate

[image]

I am trying to create a volcano plot using the following code, but I would like to put the "0" coordinate to the middle of the X-axis. Is there a way to do this in ggplot?

```
v<-ggplot(exprData.fil,aes(Effect,Effect.sig))+geom_point(aes(colour=Effect.sig),alpha=0.7)+scale_colour_gradient(low="red",high="green")
    v+ggtitle(mainTitle)
    v+xlab(expression(log[2](bar(After) / bar(Before))))+ylab(expression(-log[10]("p.value")))
```

Comment: wouldn't adding a line like  `xlim(-12, 12)`  do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `scale_x_continuous()` to set the axis limits:

```
v <- ggplot(exprData.fil,aes(Effect,Effect.sig)) +
       geom_point(aes(colour=Effect.sig),alpha=0.7) +
       scale_colour_gradient(low="red",high="green") +
       ggtitle(mainTitle) + 
       xlab(expression(log[2](bar(After) / bar(Before)))) +
       ylab(expression(-log[10]("p.value"))) +
       scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-12,12), breaks=seq(-12,12,2))
```

Another option is to use `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-12,12))`. The main difference between that and `scale_x_continuous()` is if you add any data summaries to a plot (like a smoother, mean, boxplot, etc.). If your axis limits don't include the full range of the data values, then using `scale_x_continuous()` (or `scale_y_continuous()`) will result in the data summary operation excluding the non-visible data from the summary, while `coord_cartesian()` will include all data in the summary, whether visible in the plot or not.

Comment: thanks, it works but causes some new issues - I lose the x and y axis labels after appending "scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-12,12))"

Comment: I've edited the `scale_x_continuous` function to add major tick labels. You can add a similar statement to get the y-axis labels you want. Does that address the issue?